# $ \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+9}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}})$

Tags: real-analysis

I've tried to solve the limit
$$     \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+9}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}})$$
but I'm not sure.
$ (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+9}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}}) \sim \frac{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{n^{\frac{3}{2}n}} = \frac{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{(n^n)^{\frac{3}{2}}}= \frac{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{(n^n)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \rightarrow 0$

Is it right?

Comment: I would use as an upper bound for the sum $n$ times the smallest term, and then squeeze.

Comment: Problems in your calculation: It seems to me that there are only $n$ terms, so I don't see where the $n^{3/2}$ in the numerator comes from. Also, how did you get $n$ appear in the exponent in the denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand how you got $n^{\frac 3  2n}$ etc.

Use :$ 0<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+9}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}} < \frac n {n^{3/2}} \to 0$. [Each term is bounded by $\frac 1 {n^{3/2}}$ and there are $n$ terms].

Answer (score 0):

$$       \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}}    \le   \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+k^2}  }\le   \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}} $$

for $ 1\le k \le n$ and note that $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2} } = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+1} }=0 $ then we have $$     \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+9}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}}) =0 $$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you consider :
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+k^2}}$$
$$f(n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k^2}{n^3}}}$$
For $n\to\infty$ we have $\frac{k^2}{n^3}\to 0$. Thus $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k^2}{n^3}}}\sim \sum_{k=1}^n(1)=n$
$$f(n)\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}}n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$$
Note that $f(n)$ is not equivalent to $ \frac{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{(n^n)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ but is equivalent to $n^{-1/2}$. You can check it by numerical computation which shows a very good agreement with $n^{-1/2}$. Anyways this doesn't change the conclusion $f(n)\to 0$.

[image]

For example with $n=10000$ :

$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+k^2}}=0.00999983...$ compared to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0.01$

Even more accurate asymptotic series can be derived. For example :

$f(n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1-\frac{1}{6n}-\frac{7}{40n^2}+\frac{5}{84n^3}+O(\frac{1}{n^4})\right)$

[image]